# How to detect why the error happens

Tags: android, google-play, stack-trace

The app is in the market and sometimes it reports a crash. The issue occured 5 times on 3 different devices with different Android versions. The stacktrace differs a bit depending on the android version, but mostly looks like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp (TextView.java:7465)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch (KeyEvent.java:2750)
at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent (View.java:11724)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent (ViewGroup.java:1845)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent (DecorView.java:591)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1829)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent (Activity.java:3280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatActivity.java:534)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:316)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent (DecorView.java:401)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4747)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:4619)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4161)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4180)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4307)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4188)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4364)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4161)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4180)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4188)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4161)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6682)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:6656)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6617)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage (ViewRootImpl.java:3944)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6501)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

How can I understand where the issue happens to test, debug and fix it?

Comment: 1. Get a device the problem appears on, and try to reproduce.
2. Write and roll out some diagnostic code - to get an idea of the exact circumstances.
3. Look at the code and check for edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

@i.terrible thank you for your suggestions.
To understand the issue I had to check the crash logs and videos google provided (luckily the issue also appeared on google's emulators and their logs were more informative). The reason of the issue is in the imeOptions of the EditText. I've put actionDone there to avoid focusing unfocusable views and that has fixed the issue.